# Как свернуть консольное окно selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-basic, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Запуск хрома таков.

```
Me.driver = New ChromeDriver("chromedriver", options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(32000))
```

При запуске сперва появляется консольное окно, которое хотелось бы свернуть, если это возможно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот пример для браузера Фантом:

```
   var serviceJs = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
   serviceJs.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

   Instance = new PhantomJSDriver(serviceJs, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
```

на других будет +- так же.

вот для хрома и на VB:

```
Dim service As OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverService = OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService()
service.HideCommandPromptWindow = True

Dim chromeOptions As New OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions()

Dim driver As IWebDriver = New ChromeDriver(service, chromeOptions)
```

Взято отсюда:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112574/selenium-with-chrome-shows-console-window-of-chrome-driver-get-page-complete-e

Comment: `                Dim service As ChromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService
                service.HideCommandPromptWindow = True
                Me.driver = New ChromeDriver(service, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(32000))` Выдает ошибку что не может стартонуть браузер...

Comment: смотри ошибку. Скорее всего нужно подобрать немного другой набор входных параметров в инициализации хромДрайвера. Без ошибки ничего подсказать не могу.

Comment: у меня работала программа с запуском строкой типа
`Me.driver = New ChromeDriver("chromedriver", options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(32000))`

Comment: я выше кинул линку на нужный тебе код.

Answer (score 1):

...

```
ChromeDriverService chromeservice = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
   chromeservice.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;  //спрятать консоль 
   IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeservice);

   FirefoxDriverService firefoxservice = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
   firefoxservice.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;  //спрятать консоль 
   IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxservice);
```

...
[Больше инструкций по ссылке](https://www.brainbeast.best/ru/faq-about-selenium-webdriver-on-c-sharp-with-examples/)