# Спрятать командную строку chromedriver selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Помогите мне пожалуйста перенести код:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35818436/hide-silence-chromedriver-window
на язык python.Я копался в файлах selenium и путного в голову ничего не пришло.
Возможен ли вообще запуск без появляющейся командной строки chromedriver'a?

Comment: запустите chromedriver в Питоне и убедитесь, что окошко с консолью появляется. Отредактируйте ваш вопрос и добавьте минимальный пример кода на Питоне. Если не знаете как, спрашивайте.

Comment: код 'from selenium import webdriver,driver = webdriver.Chrome()'.После этих строк запускается chrome и консоль(окно dos ) chromedriver'a.Мне нужно чтобы запускался chrome без этой консоли.Видел примеры запуска без этого окна но на других языках,но для python найти не могу.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [How do I hide the console when I use os.system() or subprocess.call()?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7006238/4279)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [hide chromeDriver console in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33983860/4279)

Comment: а я ничего не делал особого - у меня такого окошка не появляется

Answer (score 0):

Вот сдесь я отвечал на даный вопрос, хотя и на другом языке. Подход будет тот же.

[Как свернуть консольное окно selenium webdriver](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499431/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be-selenium-webdriver/555597#555597)

Comment: У него есть консольное окно? Ни разу не видел))